# rxjs: how to return the result from another observable from catchError

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using rxjs 6.5 and angular. Basically, I want to have a method in my service that:

- returns the status from a 1st api calls if the api responds
- returns the status from a 2nd (different) api call if the 1st one failed
- returns a dummy value if that 2nd call failed

Here is what I have so far. I think I need to use `flatMap/mergeMap`, but I cannot figure how.

**service.ts**

```
public getStatus()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://api.com/status1')
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => {
            //makes 2nd api call here
            return this.http.get('http://api.com/status2')

            .pipe(catchError(() =>
            {
              //both calls failed
              return of({
                  data: 'blah',
                  success: false
                });

            }))

        }));
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
this.service.getStatus().subscribe(status=>this.status = status);
```

Could somebody help?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792981/handle-multiple-http-requests-and-wait-for-all-to-complete-using-angular-rxjs-ob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method works, but doesn't look that nice with nested pipes. There is one easy thing you could do though:

```
      // Use 'of' operator to "fake" a successful API call.
      // Use 'throwError' operator to "fake" a failed API call.
      public getStatus()
      {
        return of('firstApiCall')
          .pipe(
            catchError(() => {
              //makes 2nd api call here
              return of('secondApiCall')
            }),
            catchError(() =>
              {
                //both calls failed
                return of({
                    data: 'blah',
                    success: false
                  });
              })
          );
      }
```

You can extract the second `catchError` block to have all operators on one level - `catchError` operator will only trigger once the observable throws an error, and since you want a different error handling for each call, this would do.

Potentially you could also handle that with only one `catchError` block and do some checks of the request URL to determine what do you want to return, but I guess that would require more logic and is not worth it.

Please take a look into the provided stackblitz to see this in action:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfevnt

Comment: Thanks. Actually the problem was that I has a `map` in my 2nd API call, and in that `map` I was returning `of(value)` instead of `value` itself... Your stackblitz help me identify the problem

Comment: The rule of thumb for this issue is:

if using `switchMap` - you need to return an observable
if using `map` - you need to return a "non-observable" value